# Has the UK branch of Gringotts bank been ever broken into before?

Tags: harry-potter, gringotts

There are two known break-ins and theft in Gringotts Wizarding Bank.

> The first one was committed by Quirinus Quirrell, who was attempting to steal the Sorcerer's stone from Vault 713 but the vault was already emptied and the other one was committed by Harry Potter, Hermione Granger, and Ron Weasley for one of Lord Voldemort's Horcruxes, Helga Hufflepuff's cup from the vault of Bellatrix Lestrange.

### Have such incidents ever happened before at Gringotts?

Comment: Do you mean just the UK branch?

Comment: @Mooz yes friend

Comment: I think there is no canon resource of any other known Gringotts bank break-ins.

Comment: I wonder if Gringotts pays the owners for the stolen articles, such as making a new Horcrux of the Dark Lord for Bellatrix.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Gringotts has almost certainly been broken **into** before. The goblins display a pretty cavalier attitude towards people breaking in, they obviously expect it to happen:

> “Stand back,” said Griphook importantly. He stroked the door gently with one of his long fingers and it simply melted away.
>
> “If anyone but a Gringotts goblin tried that, they’d be sucked through the door and trapped in there,” said Griphook.
>
> “How often do you check to see if anyone’s inside?” Harry asked.
>
> “About once every ten years,” said Griphook with a rather nasty grin.

Of course, the goblins aren't worried about people breaking in because that isn't the hard part. The difficult part is getting back out once you've made it to a vault, due to all of the possible enchantments involved. That, I suspect, is why Quirrell not being caught is such a big deal. Not because he tried to rob Gringotts, or even that he made it to a vault, but because he was able to make it out again afterwards.

Comment: this was the paragraph i was thinking of, implying that Gringotts had indeed been broken into before, at least thats how i read it

Comment: Although it seems that anyone with the ability and willingness to cast the Imperius Curse could break into most vaults undetected. You tend to need a key, but those are easy to fashion, and the movies do show several vaults that are opened by mere touch by the goblins.

Answer (score 7):

**Unclear.**

To the best of my knowledge, there is currently no canon description of a successful break-in at Gringotts prior to Quirrell in *Philosopher’s Stone*. However, it is implied that this probably isn’t the first. This is Ron, telling Harry about Quirrell’s break-in:

> “Did you hear about Gringotts? It's been all over the Daily Prophet, but I don't suppose you get that with the Muggles — someone tried to rob a high security vault.”
>
> Harry stared.
>
> “Really? What happened to them?”
>
> “Nothing, that‘s why it's such big news. They haven’t been caught. My dad says it must've been a powerful Dark wizard to get round Gringotts, but they don't think they took anything, that's what's odd. 'Course, everyone gets scared when something like this happens in case You-Know-Who's behind it.”
>
> — *Philosopher’s Stone*, chapter 6, *The Journey from Platform Nine and Three-Quarters*

The fact that it’s “big news” backs up what we’d expect: that this is a rare event, but if it was the first, then I think that would be even more remarkable.

So this probably isn’t the first.

We know Quirrell probably couldn’t have done this alone, but was being aided by Voldemort. If Voldemort can assist a break into the Bank in his severely-weakened form in *Philosopher’s Stone*, then I see no reason to think that he couldn’t be able to do the same at the height of the First Wizarding War. Of course, that doesn’t mean that he did, but it would be unsurprising had he done so.

Comment: Exactly from what you have said it normally happens with a powerful dark wizard then Ron says his piece about Voldemort so more than likely he did break in before during his last reign.

Comment: If you meant Gringotts, then I don't think Voldemort would use his energy for breaking into Gringotts during the First Wizarding War. In Philosopher's Stone he had a particular goal, to steal the Philosopher's Stone. He doesn't seem to be the type to personally rob banks for the sake of gold. Even if we consider he would have needed funding during the first war, he already had a powerful army by that point by virtue of his personality alone, and even if he did want the gold and riches in Gringotts,

Comment: he would probably intimidate and coarse the officials at Gringotts somehow, instead of outright breaking in or attacking the bank

Comment: @user13267: he didn’t break in by intimidation in *Stone*. All I’m saying is that it shows that Gringotts’s security is not infalliable.

Answer (score 2):

### NO

Griphook said that breaking into Gringotts is "Impossible" and implies that the only reason Quirrell was able to break into vault 713, was that it's security was lowered after it was emptied.

> “Break into a Gringotts vault?” repeated the goblin, wincing a little as he shifted his position upon the bed. “It is impossible.”
>   “No, it isn’t,” Ron contradicted him. “It’s been done.”
>   “Yeah,” said Harry. “The same day I first met you, Griphook. My birthday, seven years ago.”
>   “**The vault in question was empty at the time**,” snapped the goblin, and Harry understood that even though Griphook had let Gringotts, he was offended at the idea of its defenses being breached. “**Its protection was minimal**.”
>   <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows - Chapter 24* - [text available on Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/book-extract-long/bargaining-with-griphook))</sub>

Of course, Griphook is speaking with his Goblin pride, so his account is probably somewhat subjective.

Comment: Yes, but how does this answer the question?

Comment: @randal'thor better?

Answer (score 0):

## Yes

It probably has been because when Ron is talking about the break-in of Vault 713 in Chapter 6 of the Philosopher's Stone(Sorcerer's Stone in America) that whenever something like this happens (something is referring to the break-in of Vault 713)in case You-Know-Who's behind it.This means that someone has broken into Gringotts before possibly Voldemort himself.

> "Course,everyone gets scared when something like this happens in case You-Know-Who's behind it."Ron Chapter 6 Philosopher's Stone.

Also when Harry and Hagrid go to take the stone out of Vault 713 Griphook says that they check if anyone is inside of one of the high security vaults every ten years which could mean that they occasionally find someone's skeleton in there which would mean that someone got in but didn't get out.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "something like this" just means "something bad, that's previously thought to be extremely difficult, if not impossible" (e.g. breaking into Gringotts **and then getting out again**), not specifically "breaking into Gringotts."